# LINQ:: Error in getting User

Tags: linq

i have a table "Users" in database. it have three colu mns

Id (bigint) PK
Username (varchar)
Password (varchar)

i want to get user based on id

i am u sing this code bt it is giving me error

```
     using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
                {

// ERROR :: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'bool'
                    MUser user = from u in db.MUsers
                                 where u.Id= 1 
                                 select u;            

                }
```

how to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from u in db.MUsers
where u.Id == 1   // notice ==
select u
```

Comment: oooooooops. a small mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
where u.Id == 1
```